# Could not load file or assembly antlr.runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, antlr, mef

I'm using MEF to add some parts to my ASP.net web application. I made a PoC project and everything works like a charm. But when I try to add it to my existing web app, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'antlr.runtime, Version=2.7.6.2,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1790ba318ebc5d56' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My project does not have any reference to antlr.runtime, and if I remove the MEF code it works fine.

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("bin"));
_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
var exports = _container.GetExports<HLResourceProviderFactoryBase>();
```

My `DirectoryCatalog` object successfully finds the assemblies where I want to get the Parts from.

Any hint on what could be the problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AssemblyInfo tool](http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/)  to see the dependency graph and find out what assembly depends on  "antlr.runtime".

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't actually check the tool, but with your comment realized that I was importing more assemblies with MEF than what I actually need... Changed the DirectoryCatalog to be AssemblyCatalog and everything worked fine :)... Anyway I´ll have a look on the tool you shared, I bet it will be useful later on...